# Why class in function can't be serialized?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, gson

I tried write code like this.

```
object TestAPI {

    fun method1() {
        data class Param(
            val param: String
        )
        println("method1:${Gson().toJson(Param("test"))}" )
    }

    fun method2() {
        println("method2:${Gson().toJson(Param("test"))}" )
    }

    data class Param(
        val param: String
    )

}

fun main() {
   method1()
   method2()
}
```

The result:

```
method1:null
method2:{"param":"test"}
```

I have looked the byteCode

```
  public final static INNERCLASS com/sola/stock/moe/sola/stock/repository/TestAPI$Param com/sola/stock/moe/sola/stock/repository/TestAPI Param
  // access flags 0x19
  public final static INNERCLASS com/sola/stock/moe/sola/stock/repository/TestAPI$method1$Param null Param
```

I guess the reason is the **null** in the second line.

I want to know some detail about this.

Is it a bug?

If not why kotlin design a class in method like this.

What's the difference between that two inner class.

Comment: The local-scoped class may not have reflections, which libraries like Gson/Jackson uses to serialize/deserialize objects. Try using [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) that does not uses runtime-serialization, instead creates entities at the time of compilation.

Comment: **kolinx.serialization** works fine.Thanks